# Hacer Update comparando 2 tablas de manera rápida en MYSQL para mas de 30mil registros

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

tengo 2 tablas una llamada: **TABLA_TARIFA** y otra llamada **TABLA_ARTICULOS**.
En **TABLA_TARIFA** se encuentra el **PriceExcTax** y en **TABLA_ARTICULOS** se encuentra el **precio_venta**
en ambas tablas existe el campo **idProduct**, el cual se llama igual en ambas tablas y contiene el mismo numero *(es el campo comparador en ambas tablas)*.

cuando ambas tablas tiene el mismo **idProduct** insertamos de **TABLA_TARIFA** el **PriceExcTax** en **TABLA_ARTICULOS** en el campo **precio_venta**

he hecho este update en **php** para **mysql**

```
$precio_query = tep_db_query("select * from TABLA_TARIFA");
while ($precio = tep_db_fetch_array($precio_query)) {
tep_db_query("update TABLA_ARTICULOS set precio_venta = '" . $precio['PriceExcTax'] . "'
where idProduct = '" . $precio['idProduct'] . "' and precio_venta = '0.0000'");
}
```

pero cuando se trata de (30mil registros en TABLA_ARTICULOS) y (40mil registros en TABLA_TARIFA), esto me tarda 15 horas en hacer el update.

la pregunta es: ***hay alguna manera de hacer este update en php mas rapido?***

NOTA:

```
articulos   CREATE TABLE `articulos` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idProduct` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `precio_venta` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25448 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

tarifa      CREATE TABLE `tarifa` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idProduct` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `PriceExcTax` decimal(15,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53210 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Hay varias cosas que convendría aclarar. 1. ¿En qué engine están tus tablas? Podrás verlo haciendo un `SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla; ` Pregunto esto porque este tipo de operaciones convendría hacerlo usando transacciones, pero ciertos engines no soportan transacciones; 2. ¿Los índices están bien puestos? 30 mil o 40 mil registros no es nada en una tabla bien construida, aunque hay otros factores que podrían influir a pesar de que los índices estén bien, como la capacidad del servidor por ejemplo; ... sigue un punto 3  ...

Comment: 3. Esto parece una operación de normalización, y si no lo es, debería serlo. ¿Por qué haces esto desde PHP y no directamente en la base de datos? Si tuvieras que hacer esto desde PHP, aunque sea periódicamente, significa que hay un error de concepto, sea en el diseño de tu base de datos o en la forma en que estás afrontando el problema. Tu BD debería estar diseñada de modo que automáticamente los datos mantengan su consistencia, sin tener que lanzarte a ejecutar operaciones de este tipo desde fuera de la BD. Como ya dije, esto sólo tendría sentido para *normalizar*, en un momento determinado.

Comment: he agregado el engine. si en una tabla hay mas registros que en la otra, no todos los idProduct coinciden en ambas tablas, solo cuando coincide hacen el update, hay alguna forma de hacer el script que haga esta tarea y que este sea llamado desde un .bat

Comment: `InnoDB` soporta transacciones. De todos modos, sospecho que hay un problema más grave, y es la forma en que estás concibiendo dar una solución a este problema. Esto NO debería resolverse, ni con PHP, ni con un `.bat` ni con nada, sino, **desde la misma base de datos**. Quizá haya que normalizar, ejecutando la consulta de normalización **una única vez**, pero al mismo tiempo, creando las condiciones en la base de datos, para que los datos, una vez normalizados, **se sigan manteniendo solos**. Para ello dispones en la base de datos de varias herramientas: TRIGGERS, integridad referencial, etc.

Comment: tengo un server que ejecuta estos comandos en php a ciertas horas de la noche, el llama a un .bat y ejecuta las instrucciones en cierto orden, una de las tareas es hacer update a dos tablas que son las de articulos y tarifa, como veras la cantidad de cada una varia, el punto comparador es el  idProduct  en ambas tablas y cuando coinciden una hace el update copiando el dato de la otra tabla si existe alguna manera de hacer esto en menor tiempo posible, me es indiferente la forma de hacerlo, siempre que sea rapido. estoy atento a tus buenas recomendaciones.

Comment: la BD tarifa hay 53210 registros esto es por que me la entregan asi, en ella hay condiciones de hecho es casi el doble de la tabla articulos, por que en esta tabla hay 2 idProduct por cada producto, es decir uno con el PriceExcTax con iva y un PriceExcTax sin iva, yo lo he descartado y he colocado solo el PriceExcTax sin IVA

Comment: asi obtengo un unico idProduct en cada tabla no repetido

Comment: Como te vengo diciendo desde el principio, tendrías que: 1. Normalizar, es decir, poner al día los datos, como quisieras que estén, y esto es mejor hacerlo desde la misma base de datos... **olvídate de tus .bat y de tus archivos php para esto**. 2. Una vez normalizado, programa un TRIGGER y/o define restricciones en tus tablas, de modo que, cuando un registro de inserte, se actualice o se borre, la base de datos se mantenga sola, sin necesidad de intervención de nadie ... Las bases de datos tienen una potencialidad enorme, la cual no aprovechas, tirándole el problema a un tercero.

Comment: vale no conocía los TRIGGER voy a investigar

Comment: PHP es mucho más lento para recorrer los registros, que la misma BD. Síguele la cuerda a los comentarios que te dejan y busca una solución que corra sólo en la BD.

Comment: Otra pregunta, ¿en tu base de datos hay **también** una tabla `producto`? Lo digo porque veo rodando una columna `idProducto` en las dos tablas que presentas aquí. Si esa tabla existe, ¿qué relación tiene con estas dos? Si no existe, ¿por qué no usas la columna `id` de `articulos` para relacionarla con `tarifas`? Tu código en PHP va lento porque debes refinar profundamente tu modelo de datos en la base de datos. Deberías crear los índices y restricciones de integridad referencial necesarios y, si fuera necesario, programar un TRIGGER para automatizar en lo adelante. Pero sin ver ...

Comment: ... otras posibles tablas (como una eventual tabla `producto`) será complicado aportar una respuesta a tu problema. Pero, vuelvo a repetir, **este no es un asunto que debas resolver en php**, estamos ante un modelo de datos mal diseñado, y mientras no diseñes bien, lo único que ocurrirá es que todo irá más lento, en la medida en que las tablas crezcan y llegará un momento en que tu aplicación empezará a bloquearse. Es importante saber también si tienes privilegios y libertad para introducir cambios en la definición de las tablas.

Comment: lo he logrado hacer directamente desde la consola myadmin va mucho mas rapido... ahora tengo otra duda UPDATE articulos set precio_compra = round(precio_compra, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); me da error

Comment: no me deja hacer round

Comment: ya se que paso estoy llamando a PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP en mysql cuando esta funcion para mysql no existe

Comment: MySQL tiene su propia función `ROUND()`, y desde el cliente de MySQL no puedes combinar con código PHP. Si quieres convertirlo a MySQL, tendrías que escribir la instrucción así: **`UPDATE articulos set precio_compra = round(precio_compra, 2);`** Para ver las reglas de redondeo que aplica MySQL, revisa [este tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-math-functions/mysql-round/) o el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html).